# Reload jQuery functions after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know a lot about jQuery, and I want know how do I reload all the functions of jQuery after a ajax call, because I add element in a  and then the new element don't work but the others work fine.

The ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#search-bar').keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            myFunction();

        }
    });

        var city = $('#search-bar').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getWeatherSearch", "Index")',
            data: { city: city },
            //async: false,
            error: function (resp) {
                var div = document.getElementById('rb-grid');
                div.innerHTML = resp.responseText + div.innerHTML;
            },
            success: function (resp) {
                $("#rb-grid").prepend(resp);
            }
        });
```

HTML:

The textbox:
                
                    @Html.TextBox("search-bar", "", new { @class = "search-bar", placeholder = "Pesquisar" })

This is where I wnat to add the new

that I create dinamically, calling the method from c# using the ajax:

```
        <ul id="rb-grid" class="rb-grid clearfix">

            <li class="icon-clima-1 rb-span-2">
                <h3>@ViewBag.CurrentCity</h3><span class="rb-temp">@ViewBag.CurrentTemp°C</span>
                <div class="rb-overlay">
                    <span class="rb-close">close</span>
                    <div class="rb-week">
                        <div><span class="rb-city">@ViewBag.CurrentCity</span><span class="icon-clima-1"></span><span style="font-size: 60px !important;">@ViewBag.CurrentTemp ºC</span><span style="font-size: 40px !important;">Min: @Next0.tempMinC ºC</span></div>
                        <div style="width: 17.5%;"><span>@Next1.date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3)</span><span class="icon-clima-1"></span><span style="font-size: 40px !important;">Max: @Next1.tempMaxC ºC <br /><br /> Min: @Next1.tempMinC ºC</span></div>
                        <div style="width: 17.5%;"><span>@Next2.date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3)</span><span class="icon-clima-1"></span><span style="font-size: 40px !important;">Max: @Next2.tempMaxC ºC <br /><br /> Min: @Next2.tempMinC ºC</span></div>
                        <div style="width: 17.5%;"><span>@Next3.date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3)</span><span class="icon-clima-1"></span><span style="font-size: 40px !important;">Max: @Next3.tempMaxC ºC <br /><br /> Min: @Next3.tempMinC ºC</span></div>
                        <div style="width: 17.5%;"><span>@Next4.date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3)</span><span class="icon-clima-1"></span><span style="font-size: 40px !important;">Max: @Next4.tempMaxC ºC <br /><br /> Min: @Next4.tempMinC ºC</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

this is how I activate Boxgrid:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        Boxgrid.init();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the element function you wrote in document.ready()

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan i add the element at the ajax success

Comment: `how do i reload all the functions of jQuery`. Where they are defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Your `keyup` should always work. What is the problem?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan i put the html.

Comment: Ok. Tell us what part of the jQuery code is not working after ajax call?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan i have a BoxGrid jQuery, that make some effects to open the items, but when add a new element it stop working, but only the boxgrid...

Comment: Ok. where is the code for `boxgrid` configuration. It is really tough to ask every time .. anyway code please

Answer (score 1):

Initialize once again in your ajax callback

```
 success: function (resp) {
     Boxgrid.init();
 }
```

Comment: i'm not using click i'm using keyup, when the user press enter in a textbox

Comment: @Vinicius, it was just an assumption made before you edit the post

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add the capacity to bind events to newly added DOM elements; your code currently is only being bound to current DOM elements.

Instead, use [$.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to do something like:

`$(<selector>).on(<event>, <callback)`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a viewModel? If so you need to rebind your viewmodel after your AJAX success function. You need to put a little more code before  can further help you.